# Should I use the FQDN as the "domain" in Django's sites framework?

Tags: django, fqdn, django-sites

I have a website where any request to the non-www domain i.e. `http://example.com` is redirected (with status 301) to `http://www.example.com` by the server.

If I'm using Django's `sites` framework, should I set the [domain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site.domain) as `example.com` or `www.example.com` ? All the documents that I've seen always refer to domain as `example.com`. I'm confused if the sites framework refers to domain as the `full qualified domain name` or just the `domain name`. Django docs define domain as "The domain name associated with the Web site". This makes me think it should be without the www part. But this breaks the sitemap (Django generates all URLs without www).

The [`PREPEND_WWW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-PREPEND_WWW) settings is another reason for the confusion. It appears as if Django wants you to just define the domain as `example.com` and then use this setting to prepend `www`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `www.example.com`, as that is the canonical url of your site. Django uses the domain amongst other things to construct fully qualified URL's, and you'll want these to point to `www.example.com`.

`PREPEND_WWW` is a setting to return a redirect if the user visits `example.com` instead of `www.example.com`. It sounds like you got this covered in your webserver. It doesn't affect the domain in any other way.

Many sites don't use `www` nowadays (e.g. www.stackoverflow.com redirects to stackoverflow.com), that's the only reason why the documentation often uses `example.com`.

Comment: I don't believe it's mentioned that it should include `www` when applicable. Feel free to open a bug report about the documentation (at code.djangoproject.com) if you feel this should be clarified.